# xCode 4.6.3 Bundle Identifier Confusion

Tags: xcode, xcode4.6.3

I am trying to recreate an app in xCode 4.6.3 using storyboards.

When I enter the bundle identifier, xCode automatically adds the app name to the end of my bundle identifier with lighter place mark text.

[image]

I believe this is added to my bundle identifier because I cannot select the provisioning profile for com.macpapa.whatthisaddress.

Any help on changing my bundle id to com.macpapa.whatthisaddress would be appreciated :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually `What-s-This-Address` is triggered by the "Product Name" having that name.

If you go to `Build Settings` and search for `Product Name`you should be able to change that to `whatthisaddress`.